# Replacing everything between nth occurrences in file

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have a file with the fields as seen below :

```
2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise | CPT||0598
2|504|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise | CPT||0598
2|505|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise || CPT||0598
2|506|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise | |CPT||0598
```

I want get the final file down to this:

```
2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
2|504|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
2|505|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
2|506|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
```

I have tried the following:

```
sed 's/|//7'
```

This is great because it removes the unwanted | delimiter, in the 7th field, however, the data sometimes has more than 1 pipe in the 7th field, which my code does not pick up on in its first run through.

Is there a way with either sed, awk, or python to remove one or more | in the 7th field so that the total | pipes are only 8 total |?

Comment: You should really try to get whatever is generating the input file fixed so it quotes any field that can contain `|` and so would be a valid CSV format, e.g. `2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|"3xPirate Ship Cruise | CPT"||0598`, so you don't have to play games like this with it afterwards.

Comment: Do you actually want two spaces between `Cruise` and   `CPT`? Or is that just a typo?

Comment: Roco, please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68271362/3832970) and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @dawg this was a typo on my part

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for the response, I'll test out your solution and check the results

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your solution, however when I tried it out it didn't quite remove all the pipes as expected. Rowboats solution worked very well for my problem

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/|[ |]*//7'
```

The `|[ |]*` is a POSIX BRE pattern that matches

- `|` - a pipe char
- `[ |]*` - zero or more spaces or pipe chars (you may also use `[[:blank:]|]*` to match any horizontal whitespace or pipe chars).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3zjPm8):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise | CPT||0598
2|504|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise | CPT||0598
2|505|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise || CPT||0598
2|506|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise | |CPT||0598'
sed 's/|[ |]*//7' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|504|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|505|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|506|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
```

If you need to match up to the seventh pipe char and then match consecutive spaces and pipes and remove all pipes but keep whitespaces, a Perl solution might be more suitable:

```perl
perl -pe 's{^(?:[^|]*\|){6}[^|]*\K\|[\s|]*}{$&=~s/\|//gr}e' file > newfile
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/IWCurV). What it does is

- `^(?:[^|]*\|){6}[^|]*\K\|[\s|]*` matches six occurrences of zero or more chars other than `|` and then a `|` char and then again zero or more chars other than a pipe (with `^(?:[^|]*\|){6}[^|]*`), `\K` omits the text matched and `\|[\s|]*` matches and consumes a pipe char and then any amount of pipe and whitespace chars
- Thanks to the `e` flag, the RHS (replacement) is treated as a Perl expression and
- `$&=~s/\|//gr` means that all pipes (`g` means multiple occurrences) are removed from the match value.

Comment: Unless my eyes deceive me the space either side of the 7th pipe should be preserved, perhaps `sed 's/|[ |]*/ /7' file`?

Comment: @potong That is probably not what OP is looking for, however, I added a perl solution for that case, since it is a short and simple one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *[|] *"; OFS="|"} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 " " $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|504|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|505|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|506|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'\s*\|\s*' -lane 'print join "|", @F[0..5], ( join " ", grep { /\S/ } @F[6..($#F-2)]),  @F[-2, -1];' in.txt > out.txt
```

Output:

```
2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|504|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|505|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
2|506|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise CPT||0598
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or, if provided, on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'\s*\|\s*'` : Split into `@F` on a literal pipe, optionally surrounded by 0 or more whitespace characters.

`@F[0..5]` : fields 0 through 5 of the input line (the first 6 fields, field indexes are 0-based).
`join " ", grep { /\S/ } @F[6..($#F-2)])` : fields from 6 until the end, except the last 2 fields, select from these using `grep` only the fields with at least one non-whitespace character (`\S`), then join them on a space into a single string.
`@F[-2, -1]` : the last 2 fields of the input line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";OFS=""} {for (i=1;i<NF;++i) if (i<7||NF-3<i) $i=$i "|"}1' file
```

or

```
sed ':a;s/|/&/9;t x;b;:x;s///7;t a' file
```

Comment: Thank you @rowboat, I found your solution to be the best at being able to remove the dirty column(field) the best as it was robust enough to remove many unwanted pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Another perl:

```
perl -lnE 'say join("  ",split(/(?: \| ?\|? ?)/,$_, 2))' file
```

Or you can use `ruby` if you want to treat it with a lightweight CSV parser:

```
ruby -r csv -lne '
    BEGIN{ options={:col_sep=>"|"} }
    CSV.parse($_, **options){ |r| 
       puts r[0..6].join("|")+" "+r[-3..-1].join("|").lstrip}
' <<< "$s"
```

Or sed:

```
sed -E 's/ \|[ |][ |]?/  /' <<< "$s"
```

Any prints:

```
2|508|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
2|504|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
2|505|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
2|506|PNP|20-dec-2015 12:32:20|3451101|0|3xPirate Ship Cruise  CPT||0598
```

---

Note:

These replicate the two spaces between `Cruise` and `CPT` in your example. If you don't want that, remove the
`+" "` part in the ruby and change `"  "` to `" "` in the perl.